# How do I display my HTTP response in a list view flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, http, httprequest, httpresponse

How do I display my response which is currently separated by commas in like a list view and preferably to do so in another page?

This is my code :

```
var response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse(
            'http://192.168.1.8:8080/HongLeong/MENU_REQUEST.do?_dc=1657717579436&table_id=25018&id_MenuAction=3&reset_context=1&ViewType=MENU_REQUEST&gui_open_popup=1&id_Window=5&activeWindowId=mw_5&noOrigUserDate=true&LocalDate=20220713&LocalTime=21061900&TimeZone=Asia/Shanghai&UserDate=0&UserTime=0&server_name=OPRISK_DATACOLLECTOR&key_id_list=&cell_context_id=0&id_Desktop=100237&operation_key=1000007&operation_sub_num=-1&is_json=1&is_popup=0&is_search_window=0&ccsfw_conf_by_user=0&is_batch=0&previousToken=1657717554097&historyToken=1657717579434&historyUrl=1'),
        headers: {HttpHeaders.cookieHeader: cookies},
      );

      ResponseModel responseModel = ResponseModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));

      var message = responseModel.response.genericListAnswer.listNode.map((x) => x.toJson()['field'][0]['field_value']).toList();

      print(message);

      Navigator.push(context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const DashboardPage()));
```

and This is my response :

```
[There are 6 Users currently in the status S030 - Approved, There are 6 Users currently in the status S030 - Approved, There are 1 Users currently in the status S020 - Submit, There are 1 Users currently in the status S020 - Submit, There are 2 Risk Department currently in the status 30 - New, There are 2 Risk Department currently in the status 30 - New, There are 2 SA Department currently in the status 50 - New, There are 2 SA Department currently in the status 50 - New, There are 2 SA Department currently in the status 50 - New, There are 2 SA Department currently in the status 50 - New, There are 1 Loss Event currently in the status LE110 - Pending Approval, 473]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ListView.builder(
 itemCount:message.length,
 itemBuilder:(context,index){
  return Text(message[index]);
  }
```

**this is how you can show the data is listview**

Comment: where do I use this ListView.builder, somehow i cant use it outside of the method. the error im getting is "message" isnt defined

Comment: you have to pass the result to next screen or use the future builder to get data and show in the listview.builder 
you are navigating to next screen when data is receieve so you have to pass the data to the next screen